# como faço para limpar campos com angular?

Tags: angularjs

Quero conseguir limpar os campos depois do submit e também aplicar a ação em outros momentos, por exemplo quando clicar no botão "voltar"
usei `delete $scope.NomedaNgModel`;
Mas ele não limpa

Comment: Acho que limpar o valor da variável no *controller* deveria resolver.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode limpar o objeto da seguinte forma, assim o `ng-model` irá espelhá-lo para a `view`:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('MinhaApp', []);

  angular
    .module('MinhaApp')
    .controller('MeuController', MeuController);

  MeuController.$inject = [];

  function MeuController() {
    var vm = this;
    
    vm.limpar = _limpar;
    vm.objeto = {};

    _iniciar();

    function _iniciar() {
      vm.objeto.nome = 'TESTE';
      vm.objeto.tipo = 'TESTE 2';
    }

    function _limpar() {
      vm.objeto = {};
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MinhaApp">
  <div ng-controller="MeuController as vm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.objeto.nome" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.objeto.tipo" />
    <button ng-click="vm.limpar()">Limpar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("testectrl", function($scope){

  $scope.limpaCampos = function(dados){
   delete $scope.teste;
    $scope.zeraCampos.$setPristine();
  } 
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testectrl" name="zeraCampos">
  
  <label>Campo1</label><input type="text" ng-model="teste.cp1">
  <label>Campo2</label><input type="text" ng-model="teste.cp2">
  <label>Campo3</label><input type="text" ng-model="teste.cp3">

  <button ng-click="limpaCampos(teste)">enviar</button>
  
</form>
```

Comment: Pra que você está utilizando a variável "teste"? Pra que serve o "$setPristine()"? O "zeraCampos" não está `undefined`?

Comment: @Sorack O $setPristine de acordo com a documentação é útil quando queremos "reutilizar" um formulário depois de salvá-lo ou redefini-lo, restaurando assim seu verdadeiro estado primitivo, no caso do zeraCampos, o angular cria um escopo do name do form automaticamente, para melhor manipular os formulários